# Commerce Address Book – need to reuse customer profile without address

Tags: 7, commerce

In addition to the default shipping and billing addresses I have added a customer profile in Drupal Commerce, where the customer can add additional info, like email for invoices, special marking on shipped goods, comments and so forth.

This info is often the same on each order and we have recieved feedback that customers dont want to fill in these fields again and again when placing orders.

I have tried out the Address Book module and it seems to work for billing and shipping addresses, but how can I reuse info from previous customer profile that does not include an address? Maybe just skip the dropdown address field and use a previous customer profile and still have the possibility to edit the info?

Anyone that can point me in the right direction?

EDIT 1: as i am trialling and testing the address book module, I realize that the dropdown menu is empty in my added customer profile (because there is no address field). I need to be able to choose which field in the added profile that should be saved as "options" in the dropdown menu. Is this possible to accomplish in code? I am not asking for complete solutions here. Mereley is it possible? If yes, are there hooks I can use?

EDIT 2: I discovered that the dropdown menu is not empty after all... it's just the human readable value that is missing. There are several empty options values that can be selected after which the field values are populated from the corresponding saved customer profile. So my question changes again (sorry about that). How can I add human readable values from one of the fields in my customer profile?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the Commerce Addressbook Extra module takes care of this. In case anyone else is searching after a smooth solution.
[Link to module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_addressbook_extra)